# Upcasting in F# with sequences

Tags: f#

I'm trying to work with expressions in F# (the System.Linq.Expression kind). Here is a quick example of the problem I am having:

```
let blah = seq {
    yield Expression.New(typedefof<'T>)
    yield Expression.Constant(1)
}
```

What I would like is for `blah` to be a `seq<Expression>`. However the sequence infers its type by the first yield, which is a `NewExpression`. This will cause the second yield to result in a compilation failure because it is a `ConstantExpression`. A working solution is to upcast all of the yields:

```
let blah = seq<Expression> {
    yield Expression.New(typedefof<'T>) :> Expression
    //or
    yield upcast Expression.Constant(1)
}
```

But that feels unwieldy, having to upcast every single time. I thought flexible types might be a possible solution as well, but I've had trouble with that as well. `seq<#Expression>` doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way I can generate a sequence of expressions without having to upcast every single one of them?

Comment: F# doesn't implicitly upcast in most situations, so I don't see the upcast keyword as unwieldy, but I don't know if there's a different way to go about it either.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714567/type-inference-in-sequence-expressions-in-f) also covers your case, especially if you don't really need a *sequence* but could use an array or list, you can add [a type annotation and it should work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16718425/1180426)...

Comment: While this was presented with a trivial example, using sequences has its advantages for me since I'll be utilizing `yield!`, but perhaps a list is a workable solution. That answer also helped me understand why the F# compiler is a little funny about the subject.

Comment: A wee bit more readable variant:
`let blah = seq<Expression> { yield Expression.New(typedefof<'T>) :> _ ; yield Expression.Constant(1) :> _ }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others already mentioned, F# does not usually automatically insert upcasts in your code, so you'll need to add a type annotation and cast or the `upcast` keyword - I think the comments already cover all the options.

There are two cases when the compiler *does* upcasts - one is when passing argument to a function and the other is when you create an array or a list literal. The second can actually be used to simplify your example:

```
let blah<'T> : Expression list = 
  [ Expression.New(typedefof<'T>) 
    Expression.Constant(1) ]
```

Here, the compiler inserts upcast to `Expression` automatically. I suppose your actual use case is more complicated - when you need sequence expressions with `yield`, this will not work because then you're writing *sequence expresions* rather than *list literals*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do "flexible types" fit into the picture anywhere here?